# comparing date text field to todays date

Tags: php, date, time

Hope you can help, I have the following code to check both, if a date field is valid, and also that it has happened in the past.  The valid format part works but it keeps saying that the Date is in the future (and therefore unacceptable) regardless of whether it is or isn't.  What am I missing here?

```
  if($_POST['DateOfCall']!=NULL)  
{  
    $dt = $_POST['DateOfCall'];  
    $array = explode("/",$dt);  

    $day = $array[1];  
    $month = $array[0];  
    $year = $array[2];  

    if(!checkdate( $day,$month, $year))  
    {  
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   ,   'alert ( "Not a Valid Date of Call" );'
   , '</script>';
    }  
    else  
    {  
    $today = date("d/m/y"); 

    if(strtotime($dt)>$today)  
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   ,   'alert ( "Date of Call is in the future..." );'
   , '</script>';
    }  
}  



}
```

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix dates in different formats. `strtotime` returns an integer (Unix timestamp) while `date` returns a textual representation (string). Replace `date("d/m/y")` with `time()` and it will work.

Comment: This works, sort of, but only based on the year, so if I enter 02/07/14 it recognises it's in the future, but if I enter tomorrows date 02/07/13 it doesn't? is there something else I need to do?

Comment: You have to be *consistent*! Either use mm/dd/yy or dd/mm/yy but do not mix them.

Comment: yep I know, after replacing date ("D>M>Y') with time() I can't see where I'm not being consistent. - I need everything to be in dd/mm/yy format as I'm in the UK. I'm a total noob as this, and struggling to see what I'm missing.

Comment: Cracked it I think.  Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

The checkdate() actually takes the parameters in this order:

```
checkdate($month, $day, $year)
```

So switch place with the $month and $day in your code.

Also a second error is you line with `if(strtotime($dt)>$today)`, where you should convert $today to unix-time as well; `if(strtotime($dt) > strtotime($today))`

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `time()` with the UNIX timestamp representation of that date:

```
if (strtotime("MM/DD/YYYY 4:00PM") > time())
{
    // given date is in future. Proceed.
}
```

Documentation: [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)